# MS Excel 2016 crashing when inserting UserForm

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, crash

I had previously installed MS Office 2007 and recently I additionally installed MS Office 2016. When I tried to add a UserForm in an empty Workbook, the Excel crashed without any explanation. When I tried to play around with compatibility it started instead of crashing, referencing [Error 336](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/activex-component-not-correctly-registered-error-336). All of the possible approaches found on the web did not solve my problem.

If someone did have same/similar problem, how did you solve it (*if you did*)?

Comment: Did you apply all the service packs and patches?